# Switch statement: is it possible to reference the case?

Tags: c#

I'm working on developing a simple game and am using the switch statement quite frequently. Is it possible to reference the specific case in question instead of typing out the constant value? For instance:

```
switch(String upgrade)
{
       case(Bullet_Power_1):
           remainingUpgrades.Remove("Bullet_Power_1");
           buyableUpgrades[i].setUpgradeId("Bullet_Power_1");
           break;
}
```

Whenever I write '"Bullet_Power_1"' is there a shortcut to reference the case as I will have to write out the string many times.

Comment: I think that `upgrade` is that string as that is what has matched the case, no?

Comment: `DoStuff("Bullet_Power_1")`?

Comment: @ErikEidt At least as written, there's a difference between the constant used to match in the case statement and the literal string used later. But that could just be a typo...

Comment: @Philip, I don't understand your point.  my point: `switch (i) { case 2: ... }` inside `case 2 ...`, `i` has the value `2`, right?  And if one chooses to `switch (i+1)`, perfectly legal, one could instead `var j=i+1; switch (j)...` leaving `j` to use in each case (e.g. as `2`) in this hypothetical, eh?

Comment: Absolutely. But `upgrade` matched the constant `Bullet_Power_1` and the function calls are made with the literal string `"Bullet_Power_1"`. Consider `const string Bullet_Power_1 = "FooBar";`.

Comment: @Philip, ah, I see your point, thx!  I inferred too much from the identifiers.

Comment: [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) might be what you are looking for.  (assuming that you are using c# 6)

Answer (score 4):

From your tiny snippet of code, I'm going to make two assumptions:

**Assumption 1. `Bullet_Power_1` is defined as:**

```
const string Bullet_Power_1 = "Bullet_Power_1";
```

If this is the case, then your `case` can just be:

```
switch(String upgrade)
{
   case(Bullet_Power_1):
       remainingUpgrades.Remove(upgrade);
       buyableUpgrades[i].setUpgradeId(upgrade);
       break;
}
```

**Assumption 2. The rest of your `switch` is something like:**

```
switch(String upgrade)
{
    case(Bullet_Power_1):
       remainingUpgrades.Remove("Bullet_Power_1");
       buyableUpgrades[i].setUpgradeId("Bullet_Power_1");
       break;
    case(Bullet_Power_2):
       remainingUpgrades.Remove("Bullet_Power_2");
       buyableUpgrades[i].setUpgradeId("Bullet_Power_2");
       break;
    ...
}
```

In which case, you can get rid of the `switch` and just do:

```
remainingUpgrades.Remove(upgrade);
buyableUpgrades[i].setUpgradeId(upgrade);
```

Comment: If your first assumption would be true, the problem would be so trivial I guess the OP would not have asked first place - but lets see what he will reply.

Comment: @DocBrown, you may be right, in which case your answer is good advice. Though you need to change eg `string foo=constNames(Bullet_Power_1);` to `string foo=constNames[Bullet_Power_1];` to make it valid syntax. ;)

Comment: Oops, that happens when you have to switch often between C# and VB ;-) Changed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for has nothing to do with those constants beeing part of a `switch` case. If you want to get the name of the constant `Bullet_Power_1` as a literal string *anywhere* in your program when you know only the value, most simple solution I can think of is to create a dictionary to hold the key/value pairs beforehand:

```
   var constNames = new Dictionary<string,string>()
   {
       {Bullet_Power_1,"Bullet_Power_1"},
       {Bullet_Power_2,"Bullet_Power_2"}
       // ...
   };
```

(note that I assume your constant `Bullet_Power_1` does not already hold the value `"Bullet_Power_1"`, otherwise this would be superfluous, it would be helpful if you please confirm this assumption).

Now, whenever you need to lookup the constant name `Bullet_Power_1`, you can write

```
      string foo=constNames[Bullet_Power_1];
```

or in your case above

```
       remainingUpgrades.Remove(constNames(upgrade));
```

In C#6, one can utilize `nameof` to fill the dictionary:

```
   var constNames = new Dictionary<string,string>()
   {
       {Bullet_Power_1,nameof(Bullet_Power_1)},
       {Bullet_Power_2,nameof(Bullet_Power_2)}
       // ...
   };
```

The advantage is that this will avoid an accidental name change of the constant (for example, by using the rename refactoring of Visual Studio), where one might forget to change the string value, too.

Answer (score -1):

Strange that no-one suggested an enumeration. What about

```
public enum Upgrade
{
    Bullet_Power_1,
    Bullet_Power_2,
    Something_Different_1
}
```

Comment: Well, your current answer does not solve the OPs problem, but if you would suggest that he exchanges his string constants by an enumeration and then show him how to convert an enum name to a string again, then it could become useful.